# SolidWorks install problem

Tags: установка

SolidWorks install problem. How to fix it?
Проблема при установке солида

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Удалите всё, что связано с Солидом. Сперва установленное - через удаление программ, затем с диска (включая тулбокс и прочие каталоги) и из реестра. Перегрузитесь. Вручную установите все пре-реквизиты. Затем установите Солид заново.

Comment: эээ… а при чем здесь c++